# Async / Await JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, async-await

shortly, I was trying to simulate `async` / `await` behavior in JavaScript but getting not expected

```
const urls = ['api1', 'api2', 'api3']

async function start() {
  for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    result = await getFromApi(urls[i])
    console.log(result)
  }
}

async function getFromApi(apiUrl) {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(apiUrl)
  }).then(apiUrl => apiUrl)
}

console.log('start ....')
start()
console.log('done ... ')
```

so the expected result should be

```
start ....
api1
api2
api3
done ...
```

but I am getting

```
start ....
done ... 
api1
api2
api3
```

Comment: same issue ..
`(async () => await start())();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function called `start()` needs be used with `await`. Also in the same time your code needs to be wrapped with `async` function.

Try as the following:

```
(async () => {
    const urls = ['api1', 'api2', 'api3']

    async function start() {
        for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            result = await getFromApi(urls[i])
            console.log(result)
        }
    }

    async function getFromApi(apiUrl) {
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(apiUrl)
        }).then(apiUrl => apiUrl)
    }

    console.log('start ....')
    await start()
    console.log('done ... ')
})();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: it does work fine, Thank You, 
but do you have any Explanation why is that needed ?? 
by the way I tried `(async () => await start())();` didn't work,
but yours did work

Comment: @ATSC: Your approach wrapped the `await` in an async function, but didn't await *that* function.  This answer wraps the whole thing in an async function and uses `await` therein.  The whole outer function isn't awaited, but it doesn't need to be in this example because nothing happens after it.

Comment: Technically `await` keyword is used to add in order to wait for a `Promise`. Read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: @David I tried this  and worked fine 
`(async () =>{`
  `console.log('start ....');`
   `await start()`
 `  console.log('done ... ')`
`})(); `

But this didn't work,,
`(async () => await start())();` WHY ??!?

Comment: @ATSC: For the same reason this answer does.  There is exactly one operation which occurs after the asynchronous operation, the second console log.  It will only happen after the async operation if that operation is awaited.  The non-working example wraps only the async operation in a function, but doesn't await that function.  The working example wraps both operations in a function, and so doesn't need to await that function.  Put another console log outside of the wrapping function to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`start()` isn't being awaited.  If this is at the top-level scope then you would probably use `.then()` on the returned `Promise` object.  For example:

```
console.log('start ....');
start().then(() => {
    console.log('done ... ');
});
```